# Uri.EscapeDataString weirdness

Tags: c#, .net, escaping, .net-4.5, percent-encoding

Why does EscapeDataString behave differently between .NET 4 and 4.5? The outputs are

- `Uri.EscapeDataString("-_.!~*'()") => "-_.!~*'()"`
- `Uri.EscapeDataString("-_.!~*'()") => "-_.%21~%2A%27%28%29"`

### [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> By default, the EscapeDataString method converts all characters except
>   for RFC 2396 unreserved characters to their hexadecimal
>   representation. If International Resource Identifiers (IRIs) or
>   Internationalized Domain Name (IDN) parsing is enabled, the
>   EscapeDataString method converts all characters, except for RFC 3986
>   unreserved characters, to their hexadecimal representation. All
>   Unicode characters are converted to UTF-8 format before being escaped.

For reference, unreserved characters are defined as follows in [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt):

```
unreserved    = alphanum | mark

mark          = "-" | "_" | "." | "!" | "~" | "*" | "'" |
                (" | ")"
```

And in [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt):

```
ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
```

### [The source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/UriExt.cs#39926dc8cc434ff4#references)

It looks like whether each character of EscapeDataString is escaped is determined roughly like this

```
is unicode above \x7F
  ? PERCENT ENCODE
  : is a percent symbol
    ? is an escape char
      ? LEAVE ALONE
      : PERCENT ENCODE
    : is a forced character
      ? PERCENT ENCODE
      : is an unreserved character
        ? PERCENT ENCODE
```

It's at that final check "is an unreserved character" where the choice between RFC2396 and RFC3986 is made. The source code of the method verbatim is

```
    internal static unsafe bool IsUnreserved(char c)
    {
        if (Uri.IsAsciiLetterOrDigit(c))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (UriParser.ShouldUseLegacyV2Quirks)
        {
            return (RFC2396UnreservedMarks.IndexOf(c) >= 0);
        }
        return (RFC3986UnreservedMarks.IndexOf(c) >= 0);
    }
```

And that code refers to

```
    private static readonly UriQuirksVersion s_QuirksVersion = 
        (BinaryCompatibility.TargetsAtLeast_Desktop_V4_5
             // || BinaryCompatibility.TargetsAtLeast_Silverlight_V6
             // || BinaryCompatibility.TargetsAtLeast_Phone_V8_0
             ) ? UriQuirksVersion.V3 : UriQuirksVersion.V2;

    internal static bool ShouldUseLegacyV2Quirks {
        get {
            return s_QuirksVersion <= UriQuirksVersion.V2;
        }
    }
```

### Confusion

It seems contradictory that the documentation says the output of EscapeDataString depends on whether IRI/IDN parsing is enabled, whereas the source code says the output is determined by the value of `TargetsAtLeast_Desktop_V4_5`. Could someone clear this up?

Comment: This question helped me figure out why I wasn't getting the expected behavior under .Net 4.5, although I didn't realize it at first. I should have read your comments on the source code more carefully!  Thanks! My stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41006873/uri-escapedatastring-behaves-different-in-nunit-test-vs-asp-net-webservice

Answer (score -1):

A lot of changes has been done in 4.5 comparing to 4.0 in terms of system functions and how it behaves.
U can have a look at this thread

[Why does Uri.EscapeDataString return a different result on my CI server compared to my development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309731/why-does-uri-escapedatastring-return-a-different-result-on-my-ci-server-compared)

or

U can directly go to the following link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887(v=vs.110).aspx

All this has been with the input from the users around the world.