# Uri.EscapeDataString does not convert open and close parenthesis

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am using dot net framework 4.7.1 and VS 2017.
Uri.Escapestring does not work for open and close parenthesis

```
string str = Uri.EscapeDataString(" John ");
Result : %20John%20 - Correct

string str = Uri.EscapeDataString("(John)");
Result : (John) - incorrect - it should be - %28John%29
```

The same work in my colleague machine with same set of configurations

Any help ?

Comment: The code works fine on my machine. .NET Framework 4.6.1, VS 2017.

Comment: :) The same work in my colleague machine with same set of configurations , but not for me :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Uri.EscapeDataString return a different result on my CI server compared to my development machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309731/why-does-uri-escapedatastring-return-a-different-result-on-my-ci-server-compared) - also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41006873/uri-escapedatastring-behaves-different-in-nunit-test-vs-asp-net-webservice .